# Changing text in multiple text boxes to numbers in VB2008

Tags: vb.net

I am looking to change text of 5 letters in a set of 9 text boxes, numbered A2, A3, A4 to A9, to co-ordinates in the form "-y,x,z". This is so they can be written into a KML file for Google Earth. There is 9 text boxes in a row and there are 16 5 letter words that need changed. I was wondering if there was a better way of doing it than using a "Select Case" statement for the 16 words for each text box.

This is part of the "Select Case" I was using:

```
Select Case A2.Text
        Case "RESNO"
            A2.Text = "-15,55,0"
        Case "DOGAL"
            A2.Text = "-15,54,0"
    End Select
```

The "Case..." statement for each of the 16 words that could be in any of the text boxes.

Many thanks, James

Please let me know if I need to clarify anything.

Comment: whats is wrong with what you have there?  other than a dictionary would work without the case statement

Comment: I just wondered if there was a simplier way of doing it once that would cover all the text boxes rather than each case listed for each text box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way you could simplify the code is to place the text boxes into an array and run through each of them with a For loop so that you only have one Select Case. For example:

```
Dim textBoxArr() As TextBox = {A2, A3, A4, A5, etc..}
For Each tb As TextBox In textBoxArr
    Select Case tb.Text
        Case "RESNO"
            tb.Text = "-15,55,0"
        Case "DOGAL"
            tb.Text = "-15,54,0"
    End Select
Next
```

You can also handle multiple text boxes with one block of event code:

```
Private Sub TextBox_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles A2.TextChanged, A3.TextChanged, A4.TextChanged, etc...

End Sub
```

Comment: Check out the event code I added too. I forgot that at first ;)